# Angular-Formly: Hide/Disable Fields from Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

I have a service in which i try to disable an angular-formly field:

```
formField.templateOptions.disabled = true;
```

Even though the templateOption object is correct, the field is not disabled:

```
"templateOptions": {
    "type": "text",
    "placeholder": "",
    "label": "Single Line Test",
    "disabled": true
  },
```

Is this not possible?

Thanks.

Edit: Form Code before disabling in service

```
{
  "type": "input",
  "key": "single_line_test",
  "templateOptions": {
    "type": "text",
    "placeholder": "",
    "label": "Single Line Test"
  },
  "data": {},
  "validation": {
    "messages": {},
    "errorExistsAndShouldBeVisible": false
  },
  "id": "formly_2_input_single_line_test_3",
  "name": "formly_2_input_single_line_test_3",
  "formControl": {
    "$validators": {},
    "$asyncValidators": {},
    "$parsers": [],
    "$formatters": [
      null
    ],
    "$viewChangeListeners": [],
    "$untouched": true,
    "$touched": false,
    "$pristine": true,
    "$dirty": false,
    "$valid": true,
    "$invalid": false,
    "$error": {},
    "$name": "formly_2_input_single_line_test_3",
    "$options": null
  }
},
```

Comment: can you post the code for the form too?

Answer (score 3):

If you want a property to be dynamic, you must use `expressionProperties`. Technically, you don't have to see it via an expression property, but it needs to be present in expression properties because formly has an optimization that basically says if it's not on there, then it won't watch for changes. This is a performance optimization.

You can see dynamic disabled working in this example: http://angular-formly.com/#/example/intro/codementor

Comment: Also, to find out more about expression properties, go to http://learn.angular-formly.com

Comment: And, in the future, questions are easier to answer when an example is provided: http://help.angular-formly.com