# How do you disable a form input field using Angular Formly?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-formly

How do you disable a form input field using Angular Formly?  I've googled and there is no clear cut answer.  Indeed I have searched Formly's ['field configuration docs'](http://docs.angular-formly.com/docs/field-configuration-object) and there is only one instance of the word 'disable' on that page, and it has nothing to do with actually disabling the field.  Am I missing something?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32904449/angular-formly-hide-disable-fields-from-service Possibly useful?

Comment: @CollinD Yes, useful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By using the `disabled` option of `templateOptions`.  Below is how I added this to one of my form fields:

```
{
    key: 'accountNumber',
    type: 'input',
    templateOptions: {
        label: 'Account #',
        disabled: true,
        required: true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

not working
see my form
formData.Data.push({
ItemName: key,
// disabled: false,
Value: value.toString(),
templateOptions: {
disabled: true,
}
});

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).